# Unable to access git repository after restoring Jenkins configuration from backup

Tags: git, jenkins

I did jenkins configuration backup by copying files from JENKINS_HOME directory. I copied them to Jenkins home directory on a different machine with a fresh Jenkins installation. When i opened one of the jobs that requires downloading files from git repository i get

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe ls-remote -h git@git.path.com:project/main.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Load key "C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP\\ssh1234567.key": invalid format 
Permission denied, please try again. 
Permission denied, please try again. 
git@git.path.com: Permission denied (publickey,password). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But the credentials are present under Jenkins credentials. .ssh folder was copied as well. Any suggestions regarding what might have gone wrong?

Comment: I am not sure the ssh keys are actually stored in Jenkins home. They probably are *not* (Jenkins manages it itself and provides it to the Git's openssh via ssh agent protocol), because the private key is supposed to never leave the host. Can you simply generate a new key and set it up?

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurs to me, my situation is:

`I copies id_rsa.pub public key to jenkins credentials, but id_rsa.pub public key is for gitub\gitlab...  while id_rsa this private key is for jenkins credentials`

After I copies id_rsa this private key to jenkins credentials, all things work fine~